# Doesn't work creating a mailbox for user in Exchange via powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I encountered the following problem: we are using the open-source product MidPoint (IDM-System) on the project. It has a built-in SSH connector, which allows you to execute commands to manage the Exchange server. I need to create a mailbox for a new user. To do this, I use the script in MidPoint:

```
<scripts>
    <script>
        <host>resource</host>
        <language>cmd</language>
        <argument>
            <name>givenName</name>
            <path>$user/givenName</path>
        </argument>
        <argument>
            <name>familyName</name>
            <path>$user/familyName</path>
        </argument>
        <argument>
            <name>email</name>
            <script>
                <code>
                    email = user.getGivenName() + user.getFamilyName() + '@idm.ru'
                    return email
                </code>
            </script>
        </argument>
        <code>&amp; C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto -ClientApplication:ManagementShell; New-Mailbox -Name $givenName$familyName -UserPrincipalName $email -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Pa$$word1' -AsPlainText -Force)"</code>
        <operation>modify</operation>
        <order>after</order>
    </script>
</scripts>
```

As a result, the following command appears on the cmd:

```
$givenName = 'Ivan2'; $familyName = 'Ivanov'; $email = 'Ivan2Ivanov@idm.ru'; C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto -ClientApplication:ManagementShell; New-Mailbox -Name $givenName$familyName -UserPrincipalName $email -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Pa$$word1' -AsPlainText -Force)"
```

Accordingly, it does not work. I can't do anything with the arguments, they come in this order. The command is executed via cmd, I can’t fix this either.

I'm not very good at working with powershell and cmd. Does anyone know if it is possible to make the $givenName, $familyName, $email arguments taken into account when executing the New-Mailbox command in powershell? Or is this impossible?

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Displays an error: `"$givenName" is not internal or external
command, executable program, or batch file`. And the command is executed after the "&" symbol.
The second command, starting from `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`, goes to the Exchange Management Shell and gives the error: `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string`. That is, it does not see the $givenName, $familyName, $email arguments passed at the beginning.

Comment: Is this being run in a Powershell window, or a cmd.exe window? Since while cmd.exe could call the powershell process and run the rest of the command, those initial `$givenName = 'Ivan2'` etc bits at the start are specifically Powershell, so won't work / do anything in cmd.exe, so you'd end up with none of the required information being passed to the powershell commands.

Comment: Run in `cmd.exe`, by default this is configured in Midpoint. So there's no way to make it work?

Comment: Perhaps seek help on a Midpoint specific forum / github discussion list? As written above I don't see how that command would ever work in a cmd.exe setup. Also don't understand why if the app is auto-generating that command, it isn't inserting those values into the command in the first place rather than doing it via variables that aren't valid when called that way.

Comment: is `<language>powershell</language>` a valid option?

Comment: The official documentation says that script language parameter is ignored. But it is recommended to specify this parameter. I tried to do this `<language>cmd</language>`, but that doesn't work either. Link to SSH connector github https://github.com/Evolveum/connector-ssh (documentation from Evolveum)